# How to make (reverse . (:)) work?

Tags: haskell

I want to make:

```
liftM2 (reverse . (:)) ma mb
```

Where `ma` is `Monad Integer` and `mb` is `Monad [Integer]`. Obviously above doesn't work. Is there a way to make it prettier than:

```
a <- ma  
liftM (reverse . (a:)) mb
```

?

Comment: Do you mean `Monad m => m Integer`? `Monad Integer` makes no sense.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I dislike (.) sectioning, it makes my brain bleed.

```
reverse <$> ((:) <$> ma <*> mb)
```

Or more clearly

```
reverse <$> liftA2 (:) ma mb
```

Or more verbose, but with explicit points

```
(\x xs -> reverse (x:xs)) <$> ma <*> mb
```

Comment: Oh, I think the first two versions are good enough, the third one only makes things worse.

Answer (score 6):

Here is how you compose `reverse` and `(:)`:

```
(reverse .) . (:)
```

You can infer its type manually to figure out how this works.

So this should work

```
liftM2 ((reverse .) . (:))
```

Example:

```
> liftM2 ((reverse .) . (:)) (return 1) (return [2,3])
[3,2,1]
```

---

How to find it out easily?

Using a tool, such as [`pointfree`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/pointfree):

```
$ pointfree '(\h rs -> reverse $ h:rs)'
(reverse .) . (:)
```

Answer (score 0):

`reverse . (:)` doesn't type-check.

Try:

```
g ma mas = reverse <$> ((:) <$> ma <*> mas)
```